# How can I use detekt and its visitor to navigate over the AST of a given Kotlin file?

Tags: kotlin, abstract-syntax-tree, code-analysis, detekt

I need to check how can I navigate over the Kotlin AST of a given file. I do not know how can I pass this file to get a generated AST nor how can I navigate over its nodes using the Visitor pattern. My goal is to check the usage of some Kotlin operators in a given Kotlin file. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

I already tried to use Kastree (https://github.com/cretz/kastree) but it does not work if I change any part of its sample code.
I could not find how can I do this with detekt (https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check the of Mohit Sarveiya about Detekt, he explains AST, PSI and how detekt utilizes visitor pattern.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LT6m5_LO2DQ) 
[Slides](https://speakerdeck.com/heyitsmohit/static-code-analysis-with-kotlin)